# Extracting text from BeautifulSoup tag element

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I need to extra the date of publication that is stored in `<div>`.

E.g.,

```
<div class="volltextDetails"><meta content="2016-01-27T19:03:18+01:00" itemprop="datePublished"/>OTS0258, 27. Jan. 2016, 19:03</div>
```

I manage to find it with bs4:

```
 soup.find("div", {"class": "volltextDetails"})
```

But I really cannot figure out how to grab the date (`2016-01-27T19:03:18+01:00`), which is stored in the `meta content`.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "volltextDetails"}).meta['content']
|----------this will return div tag---------|go to meta and get content|
```

out:

```
'2016-01-27T19:03:18+01:00'
```

[navigating-the-tree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigating-the-tree)

Comment: Thanks! And for the link as well.